# request variable not being returned in the Django shortcut function render

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-apps

The following in part of my view file

```
def user_detail(request, username,
    template_name='auth/user_detail.html', extra_context=None):
    context = {
        'user': shortcuts.get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    }
    context.update(extra_context or {})
    return shortcuts.render(request, template_name, context)
```

and a part of my template is

```
 <ul class="nav">
    {% if request.user.username != 'steve' %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'user_detail' 'steve' %}">Steve</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if request.user.username != 'james' %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'user_detail' 'james' %}">James</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

However even If I login using either of these users, I still get this link displayed. This is because I am checking `request.user.username` and the request variable is not being passed to the template by the render function.

If I directly refer as user.username then it is fine, but that is not how I want to solve this problem because there are other similar views which return this `request` variable that I have to use.

This is all a part of `yourlabs fork` of [django-subscription](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-subscription.). I have not used the `render shortcut` before so I do not know why I am getting this error.

Any help will be be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `render` does is ensure that the templates are rendered with a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext). This, in turn, just means that the context processors are run.

The `request` context processor is [not enabled by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request). You have to add it to `settings.CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` yourself if you need. However, in your case you don't actually need it, because you're just interested in the user - and the [`auth` processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) provides this as the `user` variable.

So, to summarise, change `request.user` to just `user` and all will be well.

Comment: Thanks for the info.... But as I have written above this is just a particular example... I know I can access the `user` directly but I need to access this `request context processor` in other templates as well. Thanks a lot for the help.